Old HDD not recognized by Windows
I connected my old PC's HDD external drive to my laptop. (I have a connector to connect it. Since it requires an additional voltage to run, I've all the necessary tools and I am able to connect it to my laptop.)
However, it isn't showing up in my PC. I opened up Disk Management console by right clicking on "This PC" and then "Manage", and I found the disk is showing under the basic drive, but it's dynamic and invalid.
Help me to access to it, since I want to access the folders of the HDD.

Since the disk is accessible, but not readable, you can try a few things.

If it's encrypted, e.g., with Bitlocker, connect the drive to the original PC and decrypt it, or, safer, just copy data elsewhere. Bitlocker, in particular, makes it almost impossible to decrypt on another PC.
Try using a third-party tool such as DiskGenius or alternative to look at each partition, and try to read data. This can even work for an ext4 partition to which Windows has no native access.
If you cannot access data, then take a screen shot of the drive with the tool mentioned above and include it in the question, to better get help. Also, explain, "I have my old PC's HDD external driver, and I have a connector to connect it. Since it requires an additional voltage to run." If it's an external drive, shouldn't it just plug into a USB port? Is it a very old external drive, with SCSI or other connector? Explain the setup.

